# Wordpress report a post

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi guys I'm making a report post form using this code below:

```
$rp_options = array(
    'broring' => 'This is really boring',
    'difficult' => 'I don\'t understand this',
    'great' => 'Great stuff, need more'
);
$mail_report_to = 'me@domain.com');

function createReportPostForm() {
    global $rp_options, $post;
    $html = '
    <div id="formcont">
        <h3>Report this article</h3>
        <form id="myform">
            <p>
                <label for="name">What\'s wrong?</label>
                <select name="report-msg" id="report-msg">
                    <option val="">...</option>';
    foreach ($rp_options as $ok => $ov) {
        $html .= '
                    <option val="'.$ok.'">'.$ov.'</option>';
    }
    $html .= '
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="posturl" value="'.get_permalink().'" />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ajax_action" />
                <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_button" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>';
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('rp-form', 'createReportPostForm');
```

http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/wordpress-report-post/

I got the form but it does not send the mail can anyone tell what is missed in this code to make it worked? Thanks

Comment: You're not sending the mail. All I see is a function that generates an html form and returns it. You should also handle the post itself.

Comment: Where is the use of the [wp_mail() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)

Comment: There is JavaScript and additional PHP that does the actual processing of that form that can be found in the link you sent. What you have posted here ONLY adds the form, which is working correctly according to you.

Comment: yes but in functions.php I added all javascript functions too but javascript not working also  i changed   wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'rp-script.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 );  to   wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/rp-script.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 );   but nothing

Comment: Than just now changed  $mail_report_to = 'me@domain.com');   with this code $mail_report_to = get_option( 'admin_email' ); but this doesnt work too maybe the problem in ajax the submit button is not clickable so I tried to add type="submit" and the form action to permalink but it doesnt work